# export the variable from inside the mqtt loop and print its value outside the loop

Tags: python, mqtt, message, publish-subscribe, serial-communication

i have an MQTT program that accepts string variables named "message". how to print the variable "message" outside so that it can be exported to another python program

```
import paho.mqtt.client as paho 
import time 
def onMessage(client,userdata,msg):
    message=str(msg.payload.decode())


client = paho.Client()                  
client.on_message = onMessage       
client.connect("broker.mqtt-dashboard.com",1883)
client.subscribe("AGV1/posisi") 
client.loop_start()                     

print(message)
```

Comment: I suggest you search for the `global` keyword in python.

Answer (score -1):

just return it from the function:

```
def onMessage(client,userdata,msg):
    message=str(msg.payload.decode())
    return message
```

then in your client.on_message will get the message

Comment: That won't work, you can't return anything from the `on_message` callback because it is only ever called by the clients internal event loop so even if it returns something, you have no access to it.